# Convert dataframe to dictionary as shown

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

My dataframe is as shown

```
 name    key    value
 john    A223   390309
 jason   B439   230943
 peter   A5388  572039
 john    D23902 238939
 jason   F2390   23930
```

I want to convert the above generated dataframe into a dictionary in the below shown format.

```
{'john': {'key':'A223', 'value':'390309', 'key':'A5388', 'value':'572039'},
 'jason': {'key':'B439','value':'230943', 'key':'F2390', 'value':'23930'},
 'peter': {'key':'A5388'  ,'value':'572039'}}
```

I tried `a = dict(zip(dataframe['key'],dataframe['value']))`.

But wont give me the dataframe columns headers.

Comment: you cannot have same key inside the dictionary. you have multiple same keys inside the nested dictionary, which violates the definition of a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, I just wrote an example dictionary. It is my bad

Answer (score 2):

#### Dictionary keys must be unique

Assuming, as in your desired output, you want to keep only rows with the *first* instance of each name, you can reverse row order and then use `to_dict` with `orient='index'`:

```
res = df.iloc[::-1].set_index('name').to_dict('index')

print(res)

{'jason': {'key': 'B439', 'value': 230943},
 'john': {'key': 'A223', 'value': 390309},
 'peter': {'key': 'A5388', 'value': 572039}}
```